# Craft Queues: Job Event

Tags: control-panel, queue

In Control Panel we can see the progress of a certain job. I would like to hook on events like "DONE" or "FAILED" and do certain things in Control Panel, e.g. reloading the page, or redirecting somewhere

Update: in Craft.js line 11429, I can find

```
// Fire a setJobInfo event
this.trigger('setJobInfo');
```

Maybe I can do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In my control panel module javascript, I can do

```
Craft.cp.on('setJobInfo', function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```